# How to write a pytest unit test for a function if it uses __init__ values?

Tags: python, pytest

I like to write a unit test for the extract function by using pytest, but is depends on **init**, so my question is how may I write a unit test for extract function? Moreover I need to make sure if extract calls _funct_2 or funct_3 depend on the initialization values.

```
class Extraction:

def __init__(self, spark: SparkSession, dbutils: DBUtils, params: dict):
    self._params = params
    self._spark = spark
    self._dbutils = dbutils
    self.logger = getLogger(Extraction.__name__)

def extract(self) -> DataFrame:
    file_path = self._params["RawFilePath"]
    path_length = len(file_path)

    self.logger.info("determine extraction method based on file length: {}".format(path_length))
    if len(file_path) == 0:
        self.logger.info("funct_2/db extraction case")
        return self._funct_2()
    else:
        self.logger.info("file based")
        return self._funct_3()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but might be that you are conflating two concepts.

If you want to write a unit test to to test some Extraction functionality (that relies on a fully initialized Extraction object), you can simply write it in a test module:

Toy EG: `test_extraction.py`

```
def test_toy_extract():
    extract_obj = Extraction(...init params...)
    assert extract_obj.extract() == "Whatever"
```

Then just a matter of running `pytest` on the above module.

On the other hand, if you need setup (or teardown) behavior on a whole test module, class, or function, can do that:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/xunit_setup.html#class-level-setup-teardown

Comment: Or the answer with fixtures below, nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pytest fixtures to create one object for your tests, and then pass that object to your tests of the object methods.

```
@pytest.fixture
def edb():
    # you need to specify parameter values here
    # this should be database, not file in params
    return Extraction(spark, dbutils, params)

@pytest.fixture
def efile():
    # you need to specify parameter values here
    # this should be file in params
    return Extraction(spark, dbutils, params)

def test_extract_funct2(edb):
    # test the _funct2 use case

def test_extract_funct3(efile):
    # test the _funct3 use case
```

I think the method would be easier to test if you made filepath a parameter to `extract.` Then yo could use the same object and just change the file_path parameter. The way it is set up now, you could set _params["RawFilePath"], but that is pretty awkward.

```
def extract(self, file_path: str = None) -> DataFrame:
    if not file_path:
        file_path = self._params.get("RawFilePath")
    # rest of method
```

Also, the detection for `file_path` seems likely to throw an error, as there is no reason to include a blank value for the RawFilePath key if you aren't using it.   You can use `get` instead and then test for existence rather than by length. This is simpler and more pythonic than getting the length of a string or None value.

```
if self._params.get("RawFilePath"):
    self.logger.info("funct_2/db extraction case")
    return self._funct_2()
self.logger.info("file based")
return self._funct_3()
```